# Related posts are not showing

Tags: html, css, templates, post, blogger

I downloaded a free blogger template and since I have little background of HTML & CSS I modified it a little bit.

I used to have thumbnails of related posts (with same label) under each post, and I don't know what I did wrong but suddenly they all disappeared (although there are other posts with the same label in the blog).

This is the code:

```
<div class='post-related'>
    <div class='post-box'>
        <h4 class='post-box-title'>You Might Also Like</h4>
    </div>

    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
      <script expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=related_results_labels_thumbs&amp;max-results=3&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>                           
    </b:loop> 

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var defaultnoimage=&quot;http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_u4gySN2ZgqE/SosvnavWq0I/AAAAAAAAArk/yL95WlyTqr0/s400/noimage.png&quot;;
        var maxresults=3;
        removeRelatedDuplicates_thumbs();
        printRelatedLabels_thumbs(&quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;);
    </script>
</div>  
    <b:include data='post' name='threaded_comments'/>
</article>
<b:else/>
```

Also I found in CSS a class named ".item-related" which sets the size, float, hover of the thumbnails (I also checked that the display is not set as "hidden"), but anyways I could not find this class in HTML so is it missing?

Comment: Where is the javascript call back function `related_results_labels_thumbs`? it must be somewhere in your theme code.

Comment: I checked and there is none.

Comment: So, your code can't work without it.

Comment: How can I find it? I looked online for similar templates and they don't seem to have the function as well.

Comment: Please share your template url or code to check it. May be encrypted by the template author.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (I am using *Google Blogger*). The thumbnail of related posts didn't show. In my case, I figured out that the problem was in the Site Feed setting. Whenever I set it to **Short**, the related post disappeared. I then set it to **Until Jump Break**, and the problem was solved.

> Note: I set site feed to short or until jump break because I was
> [avoiding my articles from being auto-generated](https://writingnblogging.blogspot.com/2021/08/how-to-keep-articles-being-auto-generated.html).